# Trouble with GROUP BY/HAVING? SQL query not executing as expected

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got two queries. This query gives correct results:

```
SELECT SFRSTCR_PIDM
FROM SATURN.SFRSTCR 
INNER JOIN SATURN.SSBSECT
     ON SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = SSBSECT_TERM_CODE
    AND SFRSTCR_CRN = SSBSECT_CRN
    AND (SFRSTCR_RSTS_CODE LIKE 'R%'
     OR  SFRSTCR_RSTS_CODE LIKE 'W%') 
    AND SFRSTCR_CREDIT_HR >= 1 
    AND SSBSECT_SUBJ_CODE IN ('ASTR', 'BIOL', 'CHEM', 'ENVS', 'GEOL', 'PHYS')
    AND SSBSECT_CRSE_NUMB NOT LIKE '%L'
    AND SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE BETWEEN '&BeginAY' AND '&EndAY' 
INNER JOIN SATURN.SHRDGMR
     ON SFRSTCR_PIDM = SHRDGMR_PIDM
    AND SHRDGMR_GRST_CODE = 'AW'
    AND SHRDGMR_TERM_CODE_GRAD BETWEEN '&BeginAY' AND '&EndAY' 
    AND SHRDGMR_MAJR_CODE_1 = '&MajorCode'
GROUP BY SFRSTCR_PIDM
HAVING COUNT(SFRSTCR_CRN) = 2
ORDER BY SFRSTCR_PIDM
```

It returns 8 records that match the criteria.

This query gives incorrect results:

```
SELECT SFRSTCR_PIDM,
       SSBSECT_SUBJ_CODE,
       SSBSECT_CRSE_NUMB
FROM SATURN.SFRSTCR 
INNER JOIN SATURN.SSBSECT
     ON SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = SSBSECT_TERM_CODE
    AND SFRSTCR_CRN = SSBSECT_CRN
    AND (SFRSTCR_RSTS_CODE LIKE 'R%'
     OR  SFRSTCR_RSTS_CODE LIKE 'W%') 
    AND SFRSTCR_CREDIT_HR >= 1 
    AND SSBSECT_SUBJ_CODE IN ('ASTR', 'BIOL', 'CHEM', 'ENVS', 'GEOL', 'PHYS')
    AND SSBSECT_CRSE_NUMB NOT LIKE '%L'
    AND SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE BETWEEN '&BeginAY' AND '&EndAY' 
INNER JOIN SATURN.SHRDGMR
     ON SFRSTCR_PIDM = SHRDGMR_PIDM
    AND SHRDGMR_GRST_CODE = 'AW'
    AND SHRDGMR_TERM_CODE_GRAD BETWEEN '&BeginAY' AND '&EndAY' 
    AND SHRDGMR_MAJR_CODE_1 = '&MajorCode'
GROUP BY SFRSTCR_PIDM, 
         SSBSECT_SUBJ_CODE,
         SSBSECT_CRSE_NUMB
HAVING COUNT(SFRSTCR_CRN) = 2
ORDER BY SFRSTCR_PIDM
```

What I want it to do is return 16 records: the 8 SFRSTCR_PIDM from the first query should each be repeated twice, and each record should have an SSBSECT_SUBJ_CODE and an SSBSECT_CRSE_NUMB. What it actually does is give me 8 records with entirely different SFRSTCR_PIDM.

I'm not really sure what the issue is, but I assume there's some way to manipulate the GROUP BY clause to make this work. I'd appreciate some help.

Edit: This works but there has to be a simpler solution:

```
SELECT iv1.SFRSTCR_PIDM, 
       sect2.SSBSECT_SUBJ_CODE, 
       sect2.SSBSECT_CRSE_NUMB
FROM SATURN.SFRSTCR stcr2
   INNER JOIN SATURN.SSBSECT sect2
      ON stcr2.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = sect2.SSBSECT_TERM_CODE
     AND stcr2.SFRSTCR_CRN = sect2.SSBSECT_CRN
     AND sect2.SSBSECT_SUBJ_CODE IN ('ASTR', 'BIOL', 'CHEM', 'ENVS', 'GEOL', 'PHYS')
     AND sect2.SSBSECT_CRSE_NUMB NOT LIKE '%L'
     AND stcr2.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE BETWEEN '&BeginAY' AND '&EndAY' 
   INNER JOIN (SELECT stcr1.SFRSTCR_PIDM
               FROM SATURN.SFRSTCR stcr1
                  INNER JOIN SATURN.SSBSECT sect1
                     ON stcr1.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = sect1.SSBSECT_TERM_CODE
                    AND stcr1.SFRSTCR_CRN = sect1.SSBSECT_CRN
                    AND (stcr1.SFRSTCR_RSTS_CODE LIKE 'R%'
                     OR  stcr1.SFRSTCR_RSTS_CODE LIKE 'W%') 
                    AND stcr1.SFRSTCR_CREDIT_HR >= 1
                    AND sect1.SSBSECT_SUBJ_CODE IN ('ASTR', 'BIOL', 'CHEM', 'ENVS', 'GEOL', 'PHYS')
                    AND sect1.SSBSECT_CRSE_NUMB NOT LIKE '%L'
                    AND stcr1.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE BETWEEN '&BeginAY' AND '&EndAY' 
                  INNER JOIN SATURN.SHRDGMR dgmr1
                     ON stcr1.SFRSTCR_PIDM = dgmr1.SHRDGMR_PIDM
                    AND dgmr1.SHRDGMR_GRST_CODE = 'AW'
                    AND dgmr1.SHRDGMR_TERM_CODE_GRAD BETWEEN '&BeginAY' AND '&EndAY' 
                    AND dgmr1.SHRDGMR_MAJR_CODE_1 = '&MajorCode'
               GROUP BY stcr1.SFRSTCR_PIDM
               HAVING COUNT(stcr1.SFRSTCR_CRN) = 2) iv1
      ON stcr2.SFRSTCR_PIDM = iv1.SFRSTCR_PIDM
ORDER BY iv1.SFRSTCR_PIDM,
         sect2.SSBSECT_SUBJ_CODE, 
         sect2.SSBSECT_CRSE_NUMB
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that adding two columns to the `GROUP BY` makes the `HAVING` clause filter another groups of rows.

In the first query, you get those `SFRSTCR_PIDMs` where for given `SFRSTCR_PIDM` there are only two rows resulting from both `JOINs`.

On the other hand, the second query returns only those rows where there are only two rows in each group made of three columns: `SFRSTCR_PIDM`, `SSBSECT_SUBJ_CODE` and `SSBSECT_CRSE_NUMB`. This is entirely different thing and is the reason why you get different results.

Can you provide sample data and expected result? I would also recommend that you separate the conditions for JOINing the tables and the conditions filtering the records - it will be easier to see what's going on. Table DDLs would help as well, best of all - an example on SQLFiddle: <kbd>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)</kbd>

Comment: I came up with a solution, but it's so cumbersome I figure there has to be a better way. See edit above.

Comment: @anbisme Unless you provide sample data and expected output, it will be hard to understand what's going on in that query and recreate your actual situation in database to be able to test another solution.